# How to remove breakpoint from eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, breakpoints

I am facing strange problem with eclipse [Ganymede]. Once I added some breakpoints in my code and now even after I delete all those breakpoints, it appears again when I start the eclipse.
So, regularly first thing what I have to do after starting the eclipse is manually delete all breakpoints to start working. Probably eclipse stores the information about these breakpoints in some file and, I think, if I will delete that file my problem might be resolved. Please let me know if you have some solution for this.

Answer (score 71):

Another solution

Eclipse -> Run -> Remove All Breakpoints - for removing all Breakpoints for all Time

Eclipse -> Run -> Skip All Breakpoints - for temporary remove breakpoints

[image]

Comment: +1 This is excellent for when you've had a debug session and peppered breakpoints. Afterwards, you don't want to disable them, you want to *remove* them. Thanks! :)

Comment: this solution does not work anymore, nexft one from 
vzamanillo is OK

Answer (score 26):

Perhaps it helps to check the Breakpoints view (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>, type 'breakpoints') and see if they are inactive only or something. There, you can also deactivate them all at once (strikeout button).

Comment: That's what i do everytime i start eclipse. Those breakpoints appear again next time when i restart eclipse through some magic.

Comment: Hm, could it be some permission issue with the workspace or eclipse directories? Anything strange in workspace/.metadata/.log?

Comment: helpful answer , just serve my purpose

Answer (score 6):

You can go to debug prespective

[image]

and check or uncheck the desired breakpoint in the *Breakpoints view*

[image]

or show the view from the *Window* menu

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me to. I think it's eclipse bug. I filed a bug for it, will update once there's progress on it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a couple of "unable to load breakpoint" warnings which wouldn't go away, even after I deleted all breakpoints via the run->remove all breakpoints command.  These were on "dead code" paths which had been abandoned for use in the present project.

Closing and re-opening eclipse made them go away.