# How to remove all breakpoints of "single" file in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

I better know how to remove/disable [***all breakpoints***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986035/how-to-remove-breakpoint-from-eclipse) at one click and how to remove ***specific breakpoints*** but is there any way to remove all breakpoints of ***single file*** in eclipse?

**Example**

I have `5` breakpoints in **ServiceImpl.java** and `7` breakpoints in **DaoImpl.java** now I don't want to debug **ServiceImpl.java**.

So, is there any way to simply remove only **ServiceImpl.java** file's all breakpoint?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try to select Debug then group by as I described in below image

[image]

Now you can select only the node of your file and disable.

One click disable, one click enable

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at the breakpoints view where you can disable/remove individual breakpoints. They should also be ordered by class/file.

[image]

Comment: If you don't have that already, Window->show view->other->debug->breakpoints

Comment: @Hiru select all desired breakpoints in the file > right click > disable/remove....